# Convert Twitter Time into Datetime in Specific Format to Count Frequency of Tweets on a Day

Tags: python, json, datetime, pandas, twitter

So I have twitter data and I'm trying to count how many tweets I have on different days. So for example, in a list of 10 tweets, they may each have been created on a bunch of different days so I just want to figure out how many tweets there are for a given day (in the set of tweets).

Each object is in JSON format and the fields can be accessed as a dictionary key. In this case, to figure out when it was created, I use the 'date' field from below:

```
{'location': [Decimal('-118.3851587'), Decimal('34.0843881')], 'text': "random sample text", 'user': 'random user i cant show', 'id': Decimal('NaN'), 'date': 'Thu Oct 20 02:40:55 +0000 2016'}]
```

i.e. the date is formatted in the raw data as such:

```
Thu Oct 20 02:40:55 +0000 2016
```

I need to get that into this format:

```
2016-10-20
```

I was planning to make a pandas dataframe that would create a new row for each date as it came across one, but I'm worried that having to go through and dynamically add rows each time is expensive.

Since I know the specific range of days the tweets were in, I was going to just create a  dataframe with a pre-determined rows containing those dates.

To do that, I used the following code:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td 
d1 = date(2016, 9, 17)
d2 = date(2016, 11, 7)

delta = d2-d1
listOfDates = []
for i in range(delta.days+1):
    print(d1 + td(days=i))
    listOfDates.append(d1 + td(days=i))
```

This would output the following dates:

```
2016-09-17
2016-09-18
2016-09-19
2016-09-20
2016-09-21
...
2016-11-04
2016-11-05
2016-11-06
2016-11-07
```

This created a list of dates from start to finish with which I created a dataframe (using DataFrame.set_index where the values in the list of dates became the row values).

But now when I go through my twitter data I need to dynamically check the date from the date field in the *same format* as it is in the columns (i.e. 2016-10-20 from the raw data example above). I'm a little lost as to how I go about formatting it on the fly to the specific format above.

**EDIT**

New question (slightly unrelated but still pertinent).

So in my code, I have a list of dates but these are all datetime objects (i.e. they were generated in the block of code I have in my post and stored in "listOfDates").

I have a dataframe where the rows are dates, so I used df.set_index(listOfDates) but it says error: "KeyError: datetime.date(2016, 9, 17)".

How do I make the list show the objects in the right format instead of saying datetime.date? Might be a dumb question...

**Well, actually**, I used strftime to get it to the right format but it still says KeyError: '2016-09-17'

NVM I'm dumb. It was df.index not df.set_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make some lambda functions for formatting an individual string.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import re

unformatted = "Thu Oct 20 02:40:55 +0000 2016"

# Use re to get rid of the milliseconds.
remove_ms = lambda x:re.sub("\+\d+\s","",x)

# Make the string into a datetime object.
mk_dt = lambda x:datetime.strptime(remove_ms(x), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

# Format your datetime object.
my_form = lambda x:"{:%Y-%m-%d}".format(mk_dt(x))

my_form(unformatted)
>>>'2016-10-20'
```

Now you can assuming you have Pandas DataFrame with columns of strings in the same format you can apply your new function to all of the elements in that column like so:

```py
my_df.dates_column.apply(my_form)
```

Or you could make a lambda function to convert each item as you append it to the list in your `for` loop

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td

# Make a lambda function to directly format your datetime objects.
dt_form = lambda x:"{:%Y-%m-%d}".format(x)

d1 = date(2016, 9, 17)
d2 = date(2016, 11, 7)

delta = d2-d1
listOfDates = []
for i in range(delta.days+1):
#     print(d1 + td(days=i))
    listOfDates.append(dt_form(d1 + td(days=i)))
```

Comment: Oh you're a lifesaver. I didn't know how to use re to do that but I think I understand now. Thanks =).

Comment: No prob. The re module is awesome if you plan on doing more python I highly recommend that you look into it. It can save you a lot of time. Here is a really nice [regex cheatsheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/). Also would you mind upvoting this answer. I needs the points ;)

Comment: One more question. So in my code, I have a list of dates but these are all datetime objects (i.e. they were generated in the block of code I have in my post and stored in "listOfDates"). I have a dataframe where the rows are dates, so I used df.set_index(listOfDates) but it says error: "KeyError: datetime.date(2016, 9, 17)". How do I make the list show the objects in the right format instead of saying datetime.ate lol. Might be a dumb question...

Comment: Well, actually, I used strftime to get it to the right format but it still says KeyError: '2016-09-17'

Comment: It's a little difficult to debug this without the DataFrame that is giving you the error. Could you edit your question to include a  small example of the type of df we are looking at?